# Soap with attachment failure with Axis2 implementation

Tags: soap, soapui, attachment, apache-axis

I am migrating an old web service implemented with Axis 1.4, which receives and respond Soap With Attachment data. When I do a testing of the service with SOAP UI, I am getting error with `Invalid Reference :<content ID>`, can anyone help me on this?
I am using Java 1.8, WebLogic 10.3.6 server.

SOAP UI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:soa="http://fs.thehartford.com/soa">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soa:orchestrateAcordRequest xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <bin href="b4f63251-c62e-405f-b2fa-939abd706f43"/>
      </soa:orchestrateAcordRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error Log:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid reference :b4f63251-c62e-405f-b2fa-939abd706f43
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.MultirefHelper.processRef(MultirefHelper.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.processObject(BeanUtil.java:791)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.ProcessElement(BeanUtil.java:737)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Please share your `SOAP  request message` with HTTP header, it will help other answer.

Comment: Added the request message

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this question? I am still facing the issue. As per my analysis, the attachment is not added as a child element to the request and when the href attribute is comparing with child elements, it can't see a match.